# How to download file from asp.net webapi in angular 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I am using .net Web API at my backend. There is a method for downloading file from the server. It is as:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("recordFile")]
public BaseResponse RecordFile()
{
    ViewModel data;
    // ...something with data
    string recordPath = data.RecordPath;
    string fullpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(recordPath);
    string contentType = "application/" + Path.GetExtension(fullpath).Substring(1);
    WebClient req = new WebClient();
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.ContentType = contentType;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fullpath + "\"");
    response.BinaryWrite(req.DownloadData(fullpath));
    response.End();
    return OkRes(null, "Success", StatusCodeConstant.Ok);
}
```

When I hit the above method from the Postman, postman automatically opens the dialog to save the file.

But When using angular to download the file it return `null` data and the file does not get downloaded.

I am using this code in angular:

```
downloadRecordFile(): void {  
this._HttpClient.get(`${this.apiRoot}/api/recordFile`).toPromise().then(data => {
    console.log(data);  // returns null
});
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.